# Comparing two source locations using Class and method name

Tags: java

```
class SourceLocation {
    Class<?> sourceClass;
    String sourceMethodName;

}
```

I want to store SourceLocation object's in a hashed collection and so I need to override hashCode() for this class, however that will require me using the hashCode() of Class which does not seem to be overridden. For any class, will it only have a singleton Class representing it? If so then I do not have a problem but if there can be multiple Class objects for any given class then I am not sure what to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the result of `sourceClass.getName()` to produce a string for hashing. For best results, you should either concatenate it with the `sourceMethodName` and hash the result, or hash the two strings separately and combine them (`hash1*31 + hash2` is a common approach`).